# Copying File On Python 3

Tags: string, python-3.x

this is an Puzzle

how to copying file(text) to another file.

example:

```
test=open('c:\\test_file.txt')
```

test_file had a sentence

```
test1=open('c:\\test_file1.txt','w')
```

test_file1 i was made a blank file

if there on test_file had a sentence qwertyuiop asdfghjkl zxcvbnm.

how to copy text in test_file to test_file1?(using variable)

if you got it, please answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this

```
from shutil import copyfile
copyfile('c:\\test_file.txt', 'c:\\test_file1.txt')
```

Also look at other functions like `copy`, `copy2`, etc. in [shutil](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html) module.

Comment: im not understand what you mean rubix timer "Also look at other functions like copy, copy2," because i don't know what is shutil :v

Comment: @ariaamadeus `shutil` is a filesystem access library in Python

Comment: @ariaamadeus yes accept the answer if your problem's solved.

Comment: whats the matter with this

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user.user-PC\Desktop\test_file1.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(test1.read())
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user.user-PC\Desktop\asd.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(tes1.read())
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

Comment: `test=open('c:\\test_file.txt')`
`test1=open('c:\\test_file1','w')`
`import shutil`
`shutil.copyfile('c:\\test_file.txt','c:\\test_file1.txt')`
`test.close()`
`test1.close()`
`print(test1.read())`

Comment: @ariaamadeus you are reading the file after closing it, this gives the error. With shutil, no need to open files, directly call `copyfile`